# how to hook delay imports

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I wanted to do hooks without microsoft detours so I went to IAT hooking as it was the simplest method , but I found that some of the functions I want to hook are in the delay import table
I tried to hook it like I hooked iat table :

```
HMODULE lib = GetModuleHandleA(0);
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lib;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((uintptr_t)lib + dos->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR dload = (PIMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR)((uintptr_t)lib +
    nt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress); 
while (dload->DllNameRVA)
{
    char *dll = (char*)((uintptr_t)lib + dload->DllNameRVA);
    if (!strcmp(dll,"mydll.dll")) {
        MessageBoxA(0,"found mydll","info",0);
        PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA firstthunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((uintptr_t)lib + dload->ImportNameTableRVA);
        while (firstthunk->u1.AddressOfData)
        {
        if (firstthunk->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG) {}
        else {
            PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME byName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((uintptr_t)lib + firstthunk->u1.AddressOfData);
            if (!strcmp((char*)byName->Name,"func")) {
                MessageBoxA(0,"found func","info",0);
                DWORD oldProtect;
                DWORD tmp;
                VirtualProtect(&firstthunk->u1.Function, sizeof(uintptr_t), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
                firstthunk->u1.Function = (uintptr_t)hControlService;
                VirtualProtect(&firstthunk->u1.Function, sizeof(uintptr_t), oldProtect, &tmp);
                MessageBoxA(0, "hooked func", "info", 0);
            }
        }
        firstthunk++;
        }
    }
    dload++;
}
```

but the program crashes upon calling func
how can I hook it properly ?

Comment: *but the program crashes upon calling func* - you need run this under debugger and view exactly where it crashes at begin.

Comment: Delay loaded functions are loaded by `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` at runtime. The delay import table contains stubs that tell them which libraries and functions to load when called at runtime. Rather than hooking the delay import table, you could instead hook `GetProcAddress()`, then you can look at the requested function name and optionally hook the loaded function before returning its pointer to the caller.

Comment: How exactly is `func()` declared in the DLL, and what is `hControlService` and how is it declared and initialized before hooking the table with it?

Comment: I'm trying to hook ControlService and hControlService has the same signature and works flawlessly when hooking with Microsoft detours . I attached windbg to the target and got access violation in ntdll!LdrpResolveNonStaticDependency+0x1d0 . the stack trace : taskmgr!_delayLoadHelper2+0x2b ntdll!LdrResolveDelayLoadedAPI+0x488 ntdll!LdrpResolveNonStaticDependency+0x1d0

Comment: @RemyLebeau do you say that each time the delay loaded functions are being called the will be loaded via GetProcAddress() ? but I think this is in the first call as I hooked with detours without problems

Comment: @RbMm before debugging is this method the right for hooking delay loaded functions ?

Comment: begin from debugging. look for all data structures. look where crash exactly. this give you more then any answer

Comment: and address you need replace in `ImportAddressTableRVA` array, not in `ImportNameTableRVA` - it for name lookup only.

Comment: @RbMm thanks a lot . I'll paste the working code

Comment: with `firstthunk` declare else one `PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA ImportAddressTable= (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((uintptr_t)lib + dload->ImportAddressTableRVA`, increment both in loop - `firstthunk++, ImportAddressTable++`. one use for look names, and when name found - another `ImportAddressTable` for replace address. virtual protect need only in case protected delay load.

Comment: @dev65 "*I'm trying to hook ControlService*" - the code you showed is NOT hooking `AdvApi32.ControlService()`, it is hooking `mydll.func()` instead. That is why I asked how `func()` is declared, in case it does NOT have the same signature as your `hControlService` hook proc. And no, 
a delay loaded function does NOT call `LoadLibrary()`/`GetProcAddress()` every time it is called. The first time it is called, it loads the DLL function, and then calls it, and then subsequent times will call the loaded DLL function directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it was an example of the method I'm using and another thing : ControlService I'm hooking isn't in AdvApi32 . taskmgr doesn't import it from there you can check it

Comment: @dev65 on my Win7 64bit machine, TaskMgr imports `ControlService` from `AdvApi32`, as it should be since that is the official export for it, per [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108.aspx).

Comment: For the record, the Advapi32.dll export for ControlService is not where the real function is present. The Advapi32.dll export for ControlService will redirect over to Sechost.dll, which also exports ControlService. If you are trying to patch ControlService, target Sechost.dll instead.

Comment: Furthermore, do not hook GetProcAddress. Do not hook LdrGetProcedureAddress either. I believe that Shim hooks may target those routines anyway. Target LdrLoadDll and wait for the module for the delayed-import you want to target is loaded, and then set your patch. Then remove the LdrLoadDll patch.

Comment: @dev65 Can you please tell me *why* you want to patch ControlService so I can see if I can come up with a better solution than Remote Code Execution and API hooking? Generally, it is a bad idea because of the numerous issues it can cause and there could be a much more stable, safer and potentially documented approach for what you really wish to accomplish out of all of this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau on my windows 8.1 x64 taskmgr imports it from api-ms-win-service-winsvc-l1-2-0.dll

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR I'm only learning about PE format, manual mapping, dll injection and hooking techniques

Comment: @dev65 Okay, that makes sense then.

Comment: @dev65 "*on my windows 8.1 x64 taskmgr imports it from api-ms-win-service-winsvc-l1-2-0.dll*" - that is an internal implementation detail. The *official* export that everyone links to is the one in `advapi32.dll`, even if it internally maps to `Sechost.dll` or `api-ms-win-service-winsvc-l1-2-0.dll` or wherever. Nobody outside of Microsoft should ever be linking to any `api-ms-*.dll` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working code after RbMm comment :

```
 HMODULE lib = GetModuleHandleA(0);
 PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lib;
 PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((uintptr_t)lib + dos->e_lfanew);
 PIMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR dload = (PIMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR)((uintptr_t)lib +
      nt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress); 
 while (dload->DllNameRVA)
 {
  char *dll = (char*)((uintptr_t)lib + dload->DllNameRVA);
  if (!strcmp(dll,"mydll.dll")) {
      MessageBoxA(0,"found mydll","info",0);
      PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA firstthunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((uintptr_t)lib + dload->ImportNameTableRVA);
      PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA functhunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((uintptr_t)lib + dload->ImportAddressTableRVA);
      while (firstthunk->u1.AddressOfData)
      {
      if (firstthunk->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG) {}
      else {
          PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME byName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((uintptr_t)lib + firstthunk->u1.AddressOfData);
          if (!strcmp((char*)byName->Name,"func")) {
              MessageBoxA(0,"found func","info",0);
              DWORD oldProtect;
              DWORD tmp;
              VirtualProtect(&functhunk->u1.Function, sizeof(uintptr_t), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
              functhunk->u1.Function = (uintptr_t)hControlService;
              VirtualProtect(&functhunk->u1.Function, sizeof(uintptr_t), oldProtect, &tmp);
              MessageBoxA(0, "hooked func", "info", 0);
          }
      }
      functhunk++;
      firstthunk++;
      }
  }
  dload++;
 }
```

Comment: `firstthunk->u1.Function = (uintptr_t)hControlService;` really ? not want use `functhunk` here ?

Comment: anyway in modern os hook [delay] import more hard because api dll names

Comment: @RbMm it was a typo